# error In mysql query. need to get city name and max matches played in that city

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

```
select host_city,max(city) as res
from (
  select count(host_city) as city
  from match_results 
  group by host_city
) a
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

I am getting this error when the column `host_city` does exist in my table.

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'host_city' in 'field list'.

I am doing this in mysql

Comment: I'm not sure of the last `a`, what is it?

Comment: @user10089632 what do you think it could be?

Comment: @visible See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry, a wild guess? a typo, and I think Jacques Amar's answer is probably good enough, I didn't vote it up only because I don't understand what is this 'a'.

Comment: @user10089632 ok I'll fill you in. It's an alias. Every derived table needs one.

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks but I thought the alias in this case was `res` + an alias shouldn't be preceded with `as`?

Comment: @user10089632 Res is a column alias. As is optional

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `SELECT` `FROM` a sub-`SELECT`. The Subselect basically becomes your table, and your sub-select does not have host_city as a field. Here's what you need (if you really need a MAX - I'm not sure I follow your logic)

```
select host_city,max(city) as res
from (
    select host_city, count(host_city) as city
    from match_results 
    group by host_city
) a
GROUP BY host_city
LIMIT 0, 1000
```